# Swagger.php : how to change POST request header Content-type

Tags: laravel, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-php

I use lib: [darkaonline/l5-swagger (^5.5)](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger) (which contains swagger-php + swagger-ui), I need to change header Content-Type in my POST request to upload file (to read it in Laravel Input::file('photo') ). I read that I should add `consumes` and `produces` parameters to my swagger - this is what i have:

```
/**
 *
 * Create Building Photo
 *
 * @SWG\Post(
 *     path="/api/v1/buildings/{buildingId}/photo",
 *     security={{"oauth2": {"*"}}},
 *     tags={"building"},
 *     consumes={"text/plain", "application/json"},
 *     produces={"text/plain", "application/json"},
 *     description="Update building",
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *         name="buildingId",
 *         in="path",
 *         description="Building id",
 *         required=true,
 *         type="number",
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *          name="photo",
 *          in="formData",
 *          required=true,
 *          description="Building photo",
 *          type="file",
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Response( response=200, description="ok"),
 *     @SWG\Response( response=404, description="Building not found"),
 * )
 *
 */
```

But in request `Content-type` and `Accept` I always get `application/json` and laravel is unable to read uploaded file (when I generate request using swagger-ui). How I should change above swagger to to allow laravel read Input::file('photo') form POST request generated by swagger-ui ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solution:

```
 *     consumes={"multipart/form-data"},
 *     produces={"text/plain, application/json"},
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Please find  solution here.

You should follow this guidelines to setup Swagger in Laravel with Passport authentication and much more

https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger

Here, some listed issues that you may face during implementation.

https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger/issues/57

Comment: In January I found answer by myself. Do you find alternative answer? If yes - describe it here

Comment: I need a solution for using @OA (Open API Annotations).. It keep saying "Unexpected fields "consumes".